# ReactJS data from API

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys when i'm running this code in ReactJS

```
const callApi = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid=mykey');
    setWeather(response)
  }
```

i can get to `console.log(weather.data)` but when i try to get `console.log(weather.data.main)`
i get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined` i tried to parse that data to JSON but that didnt work either.

Here you can see that this object has this property:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 12.43,
        "feels_like": 7.81,
        "temp_min": 11.67,
        "temp_max": 13,
        "pressure": 1010,
        "humidity": 62
    },
    .....other items
}
```

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: `weather` is an array, hence `weather.data` is `undefined`

Comment: There is no `data` property shown in your `weather` state object. Please also include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. We've no idea where you are trying to console log `weather.data..main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes during the first render data isn't defined yet so use:

```
console.log(weather.data?.main)
```

and works like a `if(data)`